# Select multiple fields using findByField in JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to select mulitple values from a table where input can be any of the 5 columns of the table or a combination of those fields.

In order to use findByField in JPA I have to many combinations of findByField and call them selectively by checking which field is blanks.

Is there an easier solution to this?

I have 5 columns in a table that I would like to query on.

If user enters all 5 then i want to select using all 5 fields like below.

```
select * from table where field1 = :field1 and field2 = :field2 and field3 = :field3 and field4 = :field4 and field5 = :field5;
```

But if user enters only 2 fields, then I just want to query on those 2 fields like this.

```
select * from table where field3 = :field3 and field5 = :field5.
```

In JPA we can do `findByField1AndField2AndField3`

But i am having for 5 different input possibilities i will have to create like 120 possibilities.

So is there any simpler solution?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a very good use case for JPA Specifications, you can create a predicate for each field and using if statements for instance you can AND or OR these predicates together conditionally in order to create the query dynamically at runtime.

Comment: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/specifications.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no automatic generator to build all possible combinations of JPA queries, but you should use the power of JPA dynamic queries like this :

Build predicates for all the fields and apply them on the basis of user input.

```
public List<Employee> findByCriteria(String employeeName){
        return employeeDAO.findAll(new Specification<Employee>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Employee> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
                if(employeeName!=null) {
                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("employeeName"), employeeName)));
                }
                return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
            }
        });
    }
```

Helpful Link: https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring/spring-jpa-dynamic-query-example/

Comment: Thank you. This looks like exactly what i wanted to achieve. I will try this and update the results here.

Comment: I was able to use specification just like @Yugansh mentioned here above. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `@Query` in your `@Repository` interface and add as many params as you need.

```
 @Query(value="SELECT *
               FROM table
               WHERE (:field1 IS NULL
                      OR field1 = :field1)
               AND (:field2 IS NULL
                    OR field2 = :field2)",
        nativeQuery=true)
 public Table findMatchingTable(@Param("field1") String field1, @Param("field2") String field2)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try the native query and as you mentioned here. If this works that will be a really easy fix.

Comment: @RaghavendraHegde: I'm using similar queries in my project :). It will work.

Comment: @Mr.J4mes : I will still prefer a JPA based approach as it more standardized way and the native query approach is good but can have a lot of re-work  if migration of Database is required in the near future

Comment: @Yugansh: There's no such thing as a "standardized JPA approach". As times goes, frameworks like Spring bring along more ways to query the database. Just pick the path with least resistance. When database changes, your code needs to change, no matter which approach you take. It doesn't make sense to write 100 lines of code instead of 10 to prepare for some events that may never come.

Comment: @Mr.J4mes , still problems with Native Query is maintainability. First of all, they're generally more complex and longer than JPQL queries. But they also hardcode table and column names, rather than using class and property names.
JPQL queries are already problematic when refactoring because they hard-code class and property names in Strings. But native queries are even worse because they hard-code table and column names everywhere.

Comment: @Yugansh: Your underlying assumption is still that the database will suddenly change. In real life, people don't just do that for no good reason. After years of development, a lot code and features will be tied to a particular database design. They will mostly stay the same with a few new columns added here and there over time. Still, I showed him how to do it with native query as an example but JPQL supports named parameters as well. There's no reason why he cannot do the same with JPQL.